# Conversion in java

Tags: java

My question is pertaining to conversion in java.
I have an integer 1615021049. When in divide it by 1(which is also a float), the answer i get in float is 1.61502106E9, which when converted back to integer gives me 1615021056 which is not the original number. Kindly help.
The same works properly, if i convert the variables m and b to double.

```
int a=1615021023;
float m=1;
float b=a/m;
int d= (int) b;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `float`'s mantissa has too few bits to represent 1615021049 exactly. The latter requires 31 bits, and the former only offers 23. Hence the loss of precision.

This isn't an issue with `doubles` because a `double` has 52 bits of mantissa, enough to represent 1615021049.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats).

Answer (score 3):

There are an infinity of real numbers. There are only 32 bits in a float. So obviously, not every real can be represented accurately as a float. And the float representation makes small numbers more accurate than large ones.

Answer (score 2):

`int` has 31-bits (plus sign) to store the value whereas `float` only has 24-bit (plus an exponent and sign)

This means some large values cannot be represented without error.  If you use double which has 53-bits for the value, you won't have a problem.

In short, avoid using float unless thee is a *very* good reason to use it.

```
int i = 1615021023;
int a = (int) (double) i;
int b = (int) (float) i;
System.out.println("double: " + a + ", float: " + b + ", should be " + i);
```

prints

```
double: 1615021023, float: 1615021056, should be 1615021023
```

Answer (score 1):

In java ,

1. Integer uses 32 bits to represent its value.
2. a FLOAT uses a 23 bit mantissa, so integers greater than 2^23 will have there least significant bits truncated. For example 33554435 (or 0x200003) will be truncated to around 33554432 +/- 4
3. a DOUBLE uses a 52 bit mantissa, so will be able to represent a 32 bit integer without loss of data.
   You can also see "[Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)" on wikipedia